# Redirect User to Solr Database

Tags: solr, sunspot

So I have user A that needs to read only Database A and User B to read only Database B. I have it set up so that each user on log in will get re-directed to their own database but now I need to let them search their own solr indexes.

I am thinking of using a request handler to get the user and redirect them to the correct solr instance when they make a solr request. Am I on the right track here? Is this possible with a request handler?

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a core for every different user.